# Readtimeout error for API data with Sodapy client

Tags: python, timeout

I'm trying to make API calls on the consumer complaint dataset, available online (hhttps://data.consumerfinance.gov/dataset/Consumer-Complaints/s6ew-h6mp) with the SodaPy library (https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy). I just want to get the csv data, the webpage says it has 906182 rows,

I've followed the example on GitHub as best as I can, but it's just not working. Here's the code:

```
from sodapy import Socrata

client = Socrata("data.consumerfinance.gov", "apptoken", username="myusername", password="mypassword")

results = client.get("s6ew-h6mp")
```

I want to get the entire dataset,but I keep getting the following error:

```
ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.consumerfinance.gov', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

Any clues on how to work through this?

Answer (score 6):

By default, the Socrata connection will timeout after 10 seconds.

You are able to increase the timeout limit for the Socrata client by updating the 'timeout' instance variable like so:

```
from sodapy import Socrata

client = Socrata("data.consumerfinance.gov", "apptoken", username="myusername", password="mypassword")

# change the timeout variable to an arbitrarily large number of seconds
client.timeout = 50

results = client.get("s6ew-h6mp")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the connection is timing out because the file is too large. You can try to download a subset of the data using the *limit* option, e.g.

`results = client.get("s6ew-h6mp", limit=1000)`

You can also query subsets of the data using [SoQL keywords](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/).

Otherwise, the [sodapy](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy) module is built on the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module so looking at the documentation for that could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I need full dataset

Comment: Also, in my case, I am already limiting the query with a WHERE kwarg, so I cant use the LIMIT kwarg.  There must be a way to increase the "read timeout"??

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy/blob/master/sodapy/__init__.py#L25), the constructor of `Socrata` has a parameter for the time out. The following code example will increase the timeout time from 10 to 25 seconds:

```
from sodapy import Socrata
client = Socrata("data.consumerfinance.gov", "apptoken", timeout=25)
results = client.get("s6ew-h6mp")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this may actually resolve the issue: make sure you request the data from the API endpoint. The 4x4 ID is slightly different (when viewing the dataset [here](https://data.consumerfinance.gov/dataset/Consumer-Complaints/s6ew-h6mp), click Export then SODA API). Try:

```
results = client.get("jhzv-w97w")
```

Comment: so s6ew-h6mp is not the endpoint? what's the difference of the two?

Comment: They're both valid endpoints, but they serve slightly different purposes. I spoke with Socrata about this a while ago, but I don't remember exactly what their justification was... Sorry I can't clarify further. Did it work?